# Jmeter + Jenkins Performace plugin

Tags: jmeter

I have set thread properties as

`${__P(threads,)}`

for Number of user and

`${__P(rampup,)}`

for rampup period in jmeter GUI.

Then created a job in jenkins, chosen `'This project is parameterized'` and included String parameter `'THREADS' & 'RAMPUP'`. I have mentioned the right path for the execution, included `-Jthreads=%THREADS%` and `-Jrampup=%RAMPUP%` under Execute Windows batch command.

The right path was set for generating the performance report.

After choosing `'Build with parameters'`, assume the `'THREADS' as 10 and 'RAMPUP' as 0`, the build is successful.

The issue is with the 'Performance report' as every time the 'HTTP Request' count is displayed as 20 by default irrespective of whatever value is provided at the time of build. The thread count of 10 is not being considered as a parameter. By default the HTTP Request count shows as '20' requests instead of the actual '10' requests in reports.

Comment: What count of HTTP Request will be displayed in the report if you set THREADS to 20 on the build with parameters step? Could you show your test plan alos?

Comment: HTTP request count will be '20' if I give '20' as THREADS(count) when choosing Build with parameters option in Jenkins. Even if the THREADS is specified as '30', the HTTP request count is displayed as '20' in Performance report.

Answer (score 0):

Performance Plugin doesn't know anything about [Jenkins parameters](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/parameterized+build), most probably you configured it badly so it consumes the same .jtl results file all the time and doesn't load any updates.

Further assistance is not possible without seeing the screenshot of the [freestyle project](https://www.guru99.com/create-builds-jenkins-freestyle-project.html) or the code of your [Jenkins JMeter pipeline](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial).